# Why use the mkdir () function is much faster than using system ('mkdir path')?

Tags: c++, linux

I am creating an application and I need to create multiple folders and creating folders are inside a go.

Gotta make the most optimized, then I realized that mkdir () is considerably faster than system ('mkdir path');

Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system ("mkdir path");` calls a program `mkdir`, that is spawns a new process with all that it implies.

`mkdir()` just calls a system routine.

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir()` calls the system call documented by `man 2 mkdir`. The function is run within the same process.

`system('mkdir path')` forks a new process which runs the `mkdir` command, documented by `man 1 mkdir`, which despite the same name is a separate command that provides a command-line interface to `mkdir` system call.

Comment: Does Linux `runs the mkdir command` or instead `sh -c mkdir`?

Comment: It's not up to "Linux" to figure out what to run. Perl's system() call completely controls what gets executed, and how. The answer to your question can be found in perlfunc man page's description of the system() function.

Comment: The `system` function passes its argument to the system shell for execution.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking `mkdir` from a shell has *loads* of overhead (the shell itself, spawning a new process, *etc*) till it finally calls the same kernel code `mkdir()` calls directly.